# pgr_dijkstra working but pgr_ksp is returning empty an resultset

Tags: pgrouting, shortest-path, pgadmin-3

This pgr_ksp function is not working, as answered in an earlier [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75848/pgr-dijkstra-working-but-pgr-ksp-but-returning-anything-for-the-same-params)

```
SELECT seq , id1 , id2 , cost FROM pgr_ksp(  
    'SELECT gid as id, fnode_ as source, tnode_ as target, length as cost 
     FROM road', 71670, 97745, 2, false) ;
```

I have tried all these solutions, but nothing works. Also there are no directions indicating possible restrictions that I could find.

pgr_dijkastra is working well with output.

```
SELECT seq, id1 AS node, id2 AS edge, cost,geom 
FROM 
   pgr_dijkstra('SELECT gid as id, fnode_ as source, tnode_ as target, length as cost 
                 FROM road',71670 , 97745,false, false)
 JOIN road ON pgr_dijkstra.id2 = road.gid ;
```

Comment: Which version are you using of pgRouting (2.0 or 2.1? ).  I think some fixes happened in 2.1 not in 2.0.

Comment: it's 2.1.0 and still not working. please help asap.

Answer (score 2):

I am from the pgRouting developing team.
Can you please put this in a new issue in:
https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/issues
We need to reproduce your problem.
We are about to launch pgrouting 2.2, and if there still an issue in pgr_ksp of version 2.1 we really like to fix it in the release.
Thanks.
Vicky